# Kendo JS: How to dynamically change dataTextField value on multilanguage web-application

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, telerik

I have ViewModel with business-fields: NameEn and NameRu, which used for one busyness function, but on different languages of UI.
Kendo dropdownlist has **dataTextField** property to show ViewModel text property. How to dynamically change dataTextField value on client side?

PS: Chosen language stored on cookies

Comment: Fully translated multi-language web-application: translated labels and translated dictionary values on business-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `template` and `valueTemplate`:

```
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    ...
    dataTextField: "NameEn",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    template:'#=cookie_lang=="ru"?NameRu:NameEn#',
    valueTemplate:'#=cookie_lang=="ru"?NameRu:NameEn#'
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I already done this task like you, but without templates. Can you give a link about templates?

Comment: @Doni http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-template

Comment: @GeneR in my case dataSource is populated from ajax call and language can be switched in between.

Comment: @NithinChandran you can reinitialize dropdownlist each time you change language, but better bind single model property to dropdownlist and fill this property with value depend on selected language

Comment: @GeneR reinitialisation requires extra network call. That's something im trying to avoid here